# get data-count property value of <a> tag in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

[image]

I need to get the value of **data-count** of  which itself don't have any class or id but its parent tag has class.

> `ul -> li -> a`

`< ul >` tag has a class name "**tabs js-db-status-tabs**".
how can i navigate into tags to select data-count value of `< a >` tag

Comment: Firstly, please include the actual code in the question, not an image of it. Secondly, under what event are you trying to achieve this? Lastly, what attempts have you made to solve this yourself. If you add those attempts to the question too then we can help you debug it more effectively

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean

```js
const counts = [...document.querySelectorAll(".js-db-status-tabs a[data-count]")]
  .map(a => a.dataset.count);

console.log(counts)
```

```html
<ul class="js-db-status-tabs">
  <li><a data-count="1">One</a></li>
  <li><a data-count="2">Two</a></li>
  <li><a data-count="3">Three</a></li>
</ul>
```